# replacing regex in java string

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have this java string:

```
String bla = "<my:string>invalid_content</my:string>";
```

How can I replace the "invalid_content" piece?

I know I should use something like this:

```
bla.replaceAll(regex,"new_content");
```

in order to have:

```
"<my:string>new_content</my:string>";
```

but I can't discover how to create the correct regex

help please :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like

```
String ResultString = subjectString.replaceAll("(<my:string>)(.*)(</my:string>)", "$1whatever$3");
```

Answer (score 6):

Mark's answer will work, but can be improved with two simple changes:

- The central parentheses are redundant if you're not using that group.
- Making it non-greedy will help if you have multiple my:string tags to match.

Giving:

```
String ResultString = SubjectString.replaceAll
    ( "(<my:string>).*?(</my:string>)" , "$1whatever$2" );
```

But that's still not how I'd write it - the replacement can be simplified using lookbehind and lookahead, and you can avoid repeating the tag name, like this:

```
String ResultString = SubjectString.replaceAll
    ( "(?<=<(my:string)>).*?(?=</\1>)" , "whatever" );
```

Of course, this latter one may not be as friendly to those who don't yet know regex - it is however more maintainable/flexible, so worth using if you might need to match more than just my:string tags.

Answer (score 1):

See [Java regex tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/) and check out character classes and capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

The [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) would be:

```
/invalid_content/
```

For a simple substitution.  What more do you want?

Comment: A solution that works in Java, maybe?  Besides, I think the surrounding XML tags are needed to identify the invalid content, and that's what the OP was having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Is `invalid_content` a fix value? If so you could simply replace that with your new content using:

```
bla = bla.replaceAll("invalid_content","new_content");
```