# Java regex string replace

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I am trying to write regex for replacing string.

There are string examples:

`I am student.`

`I <a href="am.html">am</a> student.`

I want to write regex which will replace "am" with `<a>` html tag, and get second string as result of replacing the first string.

Problem is nesting in quotes and text inside tag.

For example if I try to replace string "am" in this example:

`I <a href="am.html">am</a> am student.`

Result should be:

`I <a href="am.html">am</a> <a href="am.html">am</a> student.`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [replacing regex in java string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499504/replacing-regex-in-java-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a simple case like this you could use simple lookarounds to make sure that the thing you are matching is not surrounded by `>` and `<` but that it has word boundaries (`\b`) around it:

```
(?<!>)\bam\b(?!<)
```

Comment: It looks like very nice solution. But does it covers replacing word followed by comma, question mark or exclamation?
Thank you very much.

Comment: @user1500221, yes it does, all `am`s would match in `am,am.am/am?!am-%am`.

Comment: I cannot make this work...I am using this, but i am doing somethin wrong. Link in code is some string.
tekst.replaceAll("(?<!>)\\bam\\b(?!<)", link);

Comment: I just tried this, and only problem is that it replaced am in the quotation at href attribute. Do you have solution for that maybe? Thanx again!

Comment: @user1500221, you could try `(?<!>|")\bam\b(?!<)`. Also as I see that you are new to StackOverflow: consider upvoting answers that are helpful and [accept the answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/163680) that you think are worthy.  ;-)

Comment: This problem made me StackOverflow member. :) Can I somehow modify this to exclude replacing string inside quotation? Because that string may be substring of quotation string...

Comment: @user1500221, that is difficult. You can use some tricks to solve it, but I'm not sure how to do it with Java. Perl example: `s#am|(<a\b[^<>]*+>am</a>)#$1? $1: "<a>am</a>"#sige`

Answer (score 0):

Below regex only matches `am` surrounded by whitespace.

```
str.replaceAll("(?<=\\s)am(?=\\s)","<a href=\"am.html\">am</a>")
```

Answer (score -1):

I can see some answers related to regex string posted already so there's no need for me to post another one. But as for this simple case, how about something as simple as replacing String? Or perhaps the real problem is more complicated than this? My solution for this case is:

```
s.replaceAll(" am ", " <a href=\"am.html\">am</a> ");
```

Comment: Replacing is supposed to cover replacing word followed by comma, question mark, dot or exclamation? That makes me problems.